# Поиск всех путей максимальной длины в дереве

Tags: c++, алгоритм, бинарное-дерево

Есть бинарное дерево, пусть оно будет сбаллансированное. Необходимо найти глубину дерева (максимальное расстояние от корня до листа) и вернуть все пути в дереве (их почти гарантированно несколько) с этой глубиной.

Структура ноды дерева

```
struct TreeNodeMod {
    int data;
    struct TreeNodeMod* leftChild;
    struct TreeNodeMod* rightChild;
};
```

Создается бинарное дерево

```
int * arr = new int[n];

for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    arr[i] = i;
}

TreeNodeMod * head = CreateBalancedTree(arr, 0, n-1);
```

Функция создания дерева

```
TreeNodeMod * CreateBalancedTree(int arr[], int start, int end) {

if (arr == nullptr) {
    return nullptr;
}

if (end < start) {
    return nullptr;
}

int mid = (start + end) / 2;

TreeNodeMod *n = MakeNode(arr[mid]);

n->leftChild = CreateBalancedTree(arr, start, mid - 1);
n->rightChild = CreateBalancedTree(arr, mid + 1, end);

return n;
}

TreeNodeMod * MakeNode(int x) {
TreeNodeMod * n = new TreeNodeMod;
n->data = x;
n->leftChild = nullptr;
n->rightChild = nullptr;
return n;
}
```

Сам я дошел только до печати дерева по уровням

```
void PrintTreeByLevel(TreeNodeMod * n) {

int h = TreeHeight(n);

auto prnt = [](auto&& self, TreeNodeMod * n, int lvl){
    if (n == nullptr) {
        return;
    }
    if (lvl == 1) {
        std::cout << n->data << " ";
    }
    else {
        if (lvl > 1) {
            self(self, n->leftChild, lvl-1);
            self(self, n->rightChild, lvl-1);
        }
    }
};

for (int i = 1; i < h+1; i++) {
    prnt(prnt, n, i);
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

}
```

Возможно, для этого можно как-то модифицировать фукцию подсчета глубины дерева, но я не могу сообразить, как

```
size_t TreeHeight(TreeNodeMod * node) {

if (node == nullptr) {
    return 0;
}
else
{
    int lheight = TreeHeight(node->leftChild);
    int rheight = TreeHeight(node->rightChild);

    if (lheight > rheight)
        return(lheight + 1);
    else
        return(rheight + 1);
}

}
```

Буду рад любым подсказкам и советам.

Comment: Вы бы структуру дерева приложили для начала

Comment: @Vladimir Afanasyev Действительно, как-то забыл включить. Добавил.

Comment: А как вы хотите находить узел вообще? У вас data это ключ или значение?

Answer (score 1):

В итоге сам подумал, и вот такое написал

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> FindPaths(TreeNodeMod * node) {

std::vector<std::vector<int>> paths;
size_t h = TreeHeight(node);
std::vector<int> cur_path;
cur_path.reserve(h);

FindPathHelper(node, paths, cur_path, h);

return paths;
}

void FindPathHelper(TreeNodeMod * node, std::vector<std::vector<int>> & paths, std::vector<int> cur_path, size_t path_len_max) {

// Если узел пуст, то ничего не делать
if (node == nullptr) {
    return;
}

// Добавить текущий узел в путь
cur_path.push_back(node->data);

// Если узел - лист, то проверить длину пути и запомнить путь, если он максимальной длины
if (node->rightChild == nullptr && node->leftChild == nullptr) {

    if (cur_path.size() == path_len_max) {
       paths.push_back(cur_path);
    }

}
else {
    // Если узел не лист, то рекурсивно обойти левое и правое поддерево
    FindPathHelper(node->leftChild, paths, cur_path, path_len_max);
    FindPathHelper(node->rightChild, paths, cur_path, path_len_max);

}

}
```